# Using MacBook Pro's monitor for Windows PC

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, screen

I want to use my 2014 macbook pro 13's monitor for my windows 7 pc .
How can I do this ?

my MacBook is running yosemite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't physically connect your Windows PC to your MBP so just using the monitor is not possible. You can use any of the various screen sharing solutions out there to access your PC from your Mac:

- [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/) is kind of straightforward to setup on both machines
- [TighVNC Server](http://www.tightvnc.com/) can be installed on the Windows side and connected to from your Mac by typing <kbd>Cmd-K</kbd> in Finder and entering `vnc://name-of-windows-pc` as an address

Comment: This is really the only way to do it. The advantage of course is that it is also wireless and you can use your setup in the reverse way too (i.e. use the monitor connected to your windows PC as an extension of your MBP). If you use TeamViewer make sure to check 'use over LAN' on the host end. It is practical for most non-gaming solutions.

Comment: @BenjaminR actually I want to use it for gaming as my pc monitor is mediocre .
should I pay attention to anything else ?

Comment: Both options I've listed can be tried without having to buy software, so just give it a try. But for most current games (especially action games of any kind) it probably will be a rather disappointing experience.

Comment: @Vicarious have you thought of using Bootcamp and putting Windows on your MBP alongside OS X? This would be a much better option. I assume the game you want to play is Windows-only? Can you give me the specs of both your machines plus the name of the game you want to play?

Comment: @BenjaminR yes I have.  my thought was that I could take advantage from my pc's better hardware and macbook's better screen. I didn't have an specific game in my mind.

Comment: @Vicarious it's the kind of nutty idea I would try myself, but I am afraid it belongs in the 'if only' pile as far as gaming is concerned. The latency is just going to be too low, as is the frame rate, not to mention you would never be able to run it at anywhere near the native resolution of a retina MBP in the first place and get more than a couple of very compressed frames per second so it throws out the whole notion doing this because your laptop has a better screen. I use team viewer every day and even using a web browser is laggy in this context.

Comment: @BenjaminR you're right .the quality is not going to be good .but I've found  out that steam has a streaming feature designed for this exact problem .I'll check it out and if it's good I'll probably answer the question myself.
http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/

Comment: @Vicarious That's great, I hope you can get it working well. I would say though, that patrix's answer is correct based on the terms of your actual question of monitor sharing, and the Steam streaming solution is something different. Instead, maybe post another question specifically stating the idea of gameplay streaming and answer that directly? Or, alternatively, just post your answer and leave this as the one ticked, and in your answer say "if anyone wants to do this for gaming, here is another option... etc".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your MBP monitor to stream your PC's screen specifically for gaming then you can take advantage from Steam's streaming feature.by using this feature you can stream your non-steam games too.

[Steam Streaming](http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/)

Answer (score -2):

its 5 years later and there is an answer https://spacedesk.net/

Comment: Hi Nic...Just wanted to share some advice to help you write an answer that get’s positive attention and ultimately enhances your experience here.  First off the open phrase “it’s 5 years later” is not relevant.  What is relevant is an *accurate answer.*

Comment: And speaking of answers...it’s best to actually answer the question here rather than send people to another site.  When answering, explain *why* this piece of software is suitable to answer the original question.  Finally, especially being new, you need to disclose your affiliation with the software developer because as written, this could be interpreted as spam.  I hope you ignore the down vote and continue to participate on this site.

Comment: This is also wrong, as no MacOS download exists, only an iOS version for iPad.